# wpf listbox автоматический скролл вниз

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, прокрутка, listbox

У меня есть ListBox, я добавляю в него элементы, но с появлением скролла ListBox не опускается вниз, к добавляемому элементу, а отображает первые элементы; как сделать чтобы при добавлении элемента в ListBox он опускался вниз и были видны последние добавленные элементы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(на всякий случай код)

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxChessMoves"   
                     Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 10 0 0"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Moves}"
                     Background="LightSlateGray" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="25">
                        <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding NumberOfMove}"/>
                        <Run Foreground="White" Text="{Binding WhiteMove}"/>
                        <Run Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding BlackMove}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929016/12888024

Comment: @aepot а без кодбехайнда можно как-то?

Comment: Может и можно, а зачем?

Comment: а без кодбейхайнда тип [такого](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2008/11/auto-scroll-listbox-in-wpf.html)

Comment: Ищите ответ на свой вопрос на этой статье https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796747/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-of-listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе вашего окна `MyWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)MyListBox.Items).CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged; 
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged (object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(MyListBox, 0);
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
        scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
    }
}
```

Взял код вот из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28433208/17025310), а так же комментария как добавить `CollectionChanged` для `ListBox.Items`.

Тип `ItemCollection` наследуется от `CollectionView`, который в свою очередь реализует `INotifyCollectionChanged`.